# How to export and import both conda and pip environment

Tags: conda

I have been using conda and pip excessively to manage my python package.
However, I couldn’t find a way to export them together and import them together. My goal is to replicate an exact same system on another machine.

Most of the guides available are mostly either conda only or pip only. But it is very critical to import both to achieve exact same state.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you exactly mean by `export them together`, but A simple test case below:

```
(base) C:\Users\dummy>conda create -n test_env python pip
####
TRIMMED OUTPUT
####
(base) C:\Users\dummy>conda activate test_env

(test_env) C:\Users\dummy>pip install numpy
####
TRIMMED OUTPUT
####
(test_env) C:\Users\dummy>conda env export
name: test_env
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - bzip2=1.0.8=he774522_0
  - ca-certificates=2021.10.26=haa95532_2
  - certifi=2020.6.20=pyhd3eb1b0_3
  - libffi=3.4.2=hd77b12b_0
  - openssl=1.1.1l=h2bbff1b_0
  - pip=21.2.4=py310haa95532_0
  - python=3.10.0=hbb2ffb3_1
  - setuptools=58.0.4=py310haa95532_0
  - sqlite=3.36.0=h2bbff1b_0
  - tk=8.6.11=h2bbff1b_0
  - tzdata=2021e=hda174b7_0
  - vc=14.2=h21ff451_1
  - vs2015_runtime=14.27.29016=h5e58377_2
  - wheel=0.37.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - wincertstore=0.2=py310haa95532_2
  - xz=5.2.5=h62dcd97_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h62dcd97_4
  - pip:
    - numpy==1.21.4
prefix: C:\Users\dummy\miniconda3\envs\test_env

(base) C:\Users\a-dummy> conda env export > dummy.yml
```

The output of `conda env export` gives a list of both conda and pip installed packages in the yml format that can be used for a `conda install --file dummy.yml`